# How to Measure a script's running time when run it many times

Tags: linux

I hava a node.js scrpit and I want to measure it's running time. But when I run it like this:

```
time node xxx.js
```

It just give the time of running once. If I want to measure 10000 times's running time, how do i do it?

It just like `%timeit` in ipython.

Comment: In [tag:bash], you could run it in a loop and add the value of each timing to a variable.

Comment: @cad yes, it is. But what I want just is a command, if not, I should write a script to achieve the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just time a loop:

```
time for i in {1..10000} ; do node xxx.js ; done
```

Note that it measures node's startup time, too.